# Qpython3 file deletion

Tags: delete-file, qpython3

So I've made a script that would delete files with a specific file extension, but how would I go about adding secure deletion of the file?

```
import sys
import os
from os import listdir

dir_name = "storage/emulated/0/Download/"
test = os.listdir(dir_name)

for file in test:
    if file.endswith(".zip"):
        os.remove(os.path.join(dir_name, file))
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stack Overflow. Is the code posted above what you've tried?

Comment: Also, define "secure" deletion as part of the Question with an [edit].